# Replacing characters from buffer array

Tags: c

I am attempting to create a text file and fill it with text, which contains even outer double quotes. Then I want to open this file, give it read-write access, and read the file. After reading the file, iterate over each character and replace those matching a single quote. However, for each match of a single double quote, I either replace it with two backquotes or two single quotes.

However, my attempt was to insert this one index position higher than the matching index for a double quote. This meant I needed to push all characters one step higher.

When given text input like:

```
//sometext.txt
"some text here"
"read it"
```

I get:

```````````````````````````````````````````````````
"some text here"
"read it"``````````````````````````````````````````````````
```````````````````````````````````````````````````

When using the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#define MAX_READ 50
int main(){
    int fd;
    fd = open("test.txt", O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1){
        printf("Failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char buffer[MAX_READ+1];
    ssize_t numRead;

    numRead = read(fd, buffer, MAX_READ);
    if (numRead == -1){
        printf("Failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    buffer[numRead] = '\0';
    int j = 1;
    size_t chars = sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]);
    for(int i = 0; i < chars; i++){
        
        if(buffer[i] == '"'){
            if(j % 2 != 0){

                buffer[i] = '`';
                chars++;
                while(i < chars){
                    i++;
                    buffer[i] = buffer[i-1];
                }
            }else{
                buffer[i] = '\'';
                chars++;
                while(i < chars){
                    i++;
                    buffer[i] = buffer[i-1];
                }
            }
            j++;

        }
        printf("\nString characters: %c", buffer[i]);
    }

    ssize_t numWrite;

    numWrite = write(fd, buffer, MAX_READ);
    
    if (numWrite == -1){
        printf("Failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 
    
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
``some text here''
``read it''
```

Comment: I see one example. I recommend many.

Comment: @Yunnosch right, I wanted improvements with my current attempt and logic. There are other methods but I want to start small and improve on my current decision.

Comment: Even after fixing "double brackets" I do not get "even outer double quotes".

Comment: @Yunnosch I mean we need an even number of double quotes for each sentence, i.e. "jack walked", "jill sat", etc ...

Comment: I know about three different single ticks/quotes/marks. The upper back tick, the upper forward tick and the "vertical" apostroph. From you description I understand that you want to replace `"` with two opening upper back ticks and close with two upper forward ticks. But you example contradicts that.

Comment: @Yunnosch I'm sorry, I do not understand

Comment: I recommend to simplify things and first work on simply inserting a character into a string in an array. You seem to be copying always the same character, probably because an off-by-one mistake in indexing. You need to keep the character in mind which you are going to overwrite. Otherwise you will copy the same again and again, which is the most probably explanation for the observed misbehaviour. Try to insert a "x" into "abcdefg"; e.g. between "d" and "e". That should allow you to get the basics right.

Comment: `buffer[i] = '\''; i++; buffer[i] = buffer[i-1];` copies the `\'` to the end

Comment: @BurnsBA Thanks for supporting my theory.

Comment: `size_t chars = sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]);` is wrong. it will always give you `sizeof(buffer) == MAX_READ + 1`. You have read `numRead` characters so just do `for(i=0; i<numRead; i++)`

Comment: @BurnsBA Oh I see, I cannot see why it does this though

Comment: Try stepping through the `while` loop in a debugger, or write down what happens by hand, or printf the values in the while loop.

Comment: @BurnsBA Ok I get it now, the while loop keeps using the previous value for the next value, but uses the same previous value, because the next value then becomes the initial value. Something like this! Thanks for recognising, I think I know the right approach to take now.

Comment: I probably want `O_TRUNC` in the `open` to remove existing content so new data is not appended to the existing text.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thank you for the advice, I will attempt that also.